# Entities in MVC and WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

I am working in an MVC web application. This application also use WCF service and Entity-framework.
In solution explorer I have two projects 1. MVC 2. WCF Service.
I am little bit confuse how should I use entities in MVC and WCF service.

For instance I have created Employee.cs class in Model folder in MVC. 
And in controller I call a method of Get Employee() of WCF service which returns employee class type.
In WCF service how I will return as employee type because I added that class in Model folder of MVC project which is not accessible to MY WCF service project.

So in this case how I should use that entity in such way that it can be accessible to MVC as well to my WCF service.

Please let me know you need more clarification..

Comment: What about creating another project, where you can place common classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share the same classes between the projects,create another class library and and the shared code in there.

Then reference the class library from both projects.

Comment: Someway you are correct. In MVC I have folder called Model, how I will use that one. Because I create a class library add reference both MVC and WCF service. Then my Model folder will blank...

Comment: @manaskumar, no not really, the model folder in the MVC project should be used for view models, these are usually amalgamation of the domain objects that a specific view requires to function i.e. a class containing the entity that will be edited inducing lists of objects that will be used for drop down boxes

Comment: Then I need to create one class library for Entities and another class library for Data layer which will contain edmx file includes other class files. Because data layer will be accessed by WCF as well MVC.
One doubt here suppose I need data from employee then I will create object from controller class and call methods of data layer project.

My project architecture is good? If not please provide some suggestion...

Comment: Yes you can seperate the data classes and the DTO (DataContract) classes and then map between them.